Travis CI not being able to push images to docker hub
Here is the log: https://api.travis-ci.com/v3/job/620698706/log.txt
You can see from the log that login succeeded.
Immediately after, when a docker push is run, it says permission denied.
Specifically, what does this do? WARNING: Error loading config file: /home/travis/.docker/config.json: open /home/travis/.docker/config.json: permission denied
I don't have any directory that matches /home/travis/.docker/config.json. It's definitely not part of my project.
echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | sudo docker login -u "$DOCKER_USERNAME" --password-stdin
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/travis/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
travis_time:end:13eccd05:start=1713443333438454634,finish=1713443333744799013,duration=306344379,event=after_success
[0Ktravis_fold:end:after_success.5
[0Ktravis_fold:start:after_success.6
[0Ktravis_time:start:1f64d2fc
[0K$ docker push [secure]/multi-client:v1
WARNING: Error loading config file: /home/travis/.docker/config.json: open /home/travis/.docker/config.json: permission denied
The push refers to repository [docker.io/[secure]/multi-client]
27b901d4c610: Preparing
9971954b6568: Preparing
7abfb0741b3d: Preparing
3773452b6e48: Preparing
8789db06fb83: Preparing
25e1b6e594d0: Preparing
0e87b211f7ef: Preparing
9b87c194c4dd: Preparing
1f00ff201478: Preparing
25e1b6e594d0: Waiting
0e87b211f7ef: Waiting
9b87c194c4dd: Waiting
1f00ff201478: Waiting
denied: requested access to the resource is denied

